# Dynamically define fields in a peewee model

Tags: python, peewee

This works:

```
class MyModel(peewee.Model):
    my_field = peewee.IntegerField(null=False, default=0)

    class Meta(object):
        database = db
        db_table = 'MyTable'
```

This does not work:

```
class MyModel(peewee.Model):

    class Meta(object):
        database = db
        db_table = 'MyTable'

setattr(MyModel, 'my_field', peewee.IntegerField(null=False, default=0))
```

I guess this is due to some metaclass magic done in `peewee.Model`. Indeed, I can't see it in the model's `_meta.fields`.

What would be a good way to define the fields dynamically?

Answer (score 17):

Instead of setattr, call `add_to_class`:

```
my_field = peewee.IntegerField(null=False, default=0)
my_field.add_to_class(MyModel, 'my_field_name')

# Now this works:
MyModel.my_field_name
```

Comment: Apparently this is now: `Model._meta.add_field(field_name, field)`

Answer (score 2):

This post is just to give prominence to the correct answer given by [AidanGawronski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3922132/aidangawronski) for Peewee 3.? (tested 2020-05-18).

Code such as the following succeeds:

```
class Note(Model):
    note_id = AutoField()
fields=('nx', 'ny', 'nz')
for f in fields:
    Note._meta.add_field(f, TextField(null=False))
```

Peewee's [*migrate*](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#schema-migrations) module apparently can be used to accomplish the same thing, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Seconded. This works!